# Using Char for Conditional Variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

I need help adding to a program that categorizes ages to find out whether or not an individual is eligible for a life insurance package. Rules are to add to a previous program that allows user to input age and then outputs whether they are a minor child, minor teenager, adult, or senior senior adult. Need to use char yes or no as to decide whether eligible or not. This rules to the enhancement will be also to determine eligibility. Below are the rules and the code so far.

**age                        eligible
17 or under                'n'
18-90                      'y'
more than 90               'n'**   <------new enhancement rules
 Code:

```
//12 or under         minor child
//13 - 17             minor teenager
//18 - 64             adult
//65 or over      senior adult


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int MAX_CHILD = 12, MAX_TEEN = 17, MAX_ADULT = 64; MAX_ADULT_ALLOWED = 90;
    int age;


    cout << "How old are you?";
    cin >> age;
    // additional code goes here

    if (age <= MAX_CHILD)
        cout << "You're a minor child.\n";

    else if (age <= MAX_TEEN)
        cout << "You're a minor teenager.\n";

    else if (age <= MAX_ADULT)
        cout << "You're an adult.\n";

    else if
        cout << "You're a senior adult.\n";

    else (age <= MAX_ADULT_ALLOWED)



    //if (eligible == "y")
    //cout << "You are eligible for life insurance package.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will answer your question:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

//12 or under         minor child
//13 - 17             minor teenager
//18 - 64             adult
//65 or over      senior adult

int main()
{
    const int MAX_CHILD = 12, MAX_TEEN = 17, MAX_ADULT = 64, MAX_ADULT_ALLOWED = 90;
    int age;
    char eligible ;

    cout << "How old are you?";
    cin >> age;
    // additional code goes here

    if (age <= MAX_CHILD)
        {
            cout << "You're a minor child.\n";
            eligible = 'n';
        }

    else if (age <= MAX_TEEN)
        {
            cout << "You're a minor teenager.\n";
            eligible = 'n';
        }

    else if (age <= MAX_ADULT)
        {
            cout << "You're an adult.\n";
            eligible = 'y';
        }

    else if (age <= MAX_ADULT_ALLOWED)

        {
            cout << "You're a senior adult.\n";
            eligible = 'y';
        }

    else

        {
            cout << "You're a senior adult.\n";
            eligible = 'n';
        }




    if (eligible == 'y')

        cout << "You are eligible for life insurance package.\n";

    else

         cout << "You are not eligible for life insurance package.\n";

    std::system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why is the down vote so i can coorect my self?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't down vote anyone. I am new to here but not that clueless I hope. I used your code and it seemed to work and satisfy the assignment requirements. However, I did leave out (#include "stdafx.h") and (std::system("PAUSE");) because my instructor has not discussed these in class yet so I am assuming we wouldn't use it here. Out of curiosity however why did you choose to use this? The code seems to work fine without.

Comment: Yes, it is true, you can use the code without i used them just because i was developping somthing personal and i left them there

Answer (score 0):

**You can put the print statement** `cout << "You are eligible for life insurance package.\n";` inside the `if` block **which satisfies the condition** ,no need of an extra variable for eligibility.

```
if (age <= MAX_CHILD){
    cout << "You're a minor child.\n";
    cout << "You are not eligible for life insurance package.\n";
    //eligible = 'n';

}
else if (age <= MAX_TEEN){
    cout << "You're a minor teenager.\n";
    cout << "You are not eligible for life insurance package.\n";
    //eligible = 'n';
}

else if (age <= MAX_ADULT){
    cout << "You're an adult.\n";
    cout << "You are eligible for life insurance package.\n"; 
    //eligible = 'y';
}

else if(age <= MAX_ADULT_ALLOWED){
    cout << "You're a senior adult.\n";
    cout << "You are eligible for life insurance package.\n";
    //eligible = 'y';
}

else {
    cout << "You are not eligible for life insurance package.\n";
    //eligible = 'n';
}
```

Or if you want to use a separate variable for eligibility then just assign it the value **y** inside the block which satisfies the condition otherwise assign it **n**(I have commented those lines in code), at last check for eligibility.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried an additional cout statement but wasn't able to make it work. Perhaps I was missing brackets?